# Entity class inhibits filling database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot app with an h2 database that is handled via JPA. I follow there instructions https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/. I initialize a table `debug` from a file `schema.sql`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS debug;
  
CREATE TABLE debug (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  other INT
);
```

an fill it with another file `data.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO debug (id, other) VALUES
  (0, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 3);
```

I further define an entity object:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "debug")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DebugBE {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    
    private int other;

}
```

My application.properties is just:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:h2db
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded #default
```

Versions are:

- `org.springframework.boot` plugin: version `2.3.3.RELEASE`

When I start the app and check the h2 console in the browser I can see that the table `debug` is empty. If I comment out the `Table` annotation the table is filled with the values from `data.sql` but then an empty `debugBE` table is created.

If debugBE and the definition in schema.sql diddn't fit, I'd expect a error message, but there is none. So I guess it is expected behavior that `@Table` annotated classes lead to an empty table?
How can I autofill a table from `data.sql` and read it as BE objects?

Comment: How are you populating the table?

Comment: @Andronicus I populate the table with the `data.sql` file. Spring-boot does that automatically. But it no longer works after I add `DebugBE`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to application.properties solved it.